# Pass JVM arguments to JMH

Tags: jvm, sbt, jmh

I have some JMH benchmarks that I'm trying to analyze. I want to enable GC logging to see how much garbage is being generated, but I can't figure out how to pass JVM arguments. I know JMH runs benchmarks in a forked JVM, so it's not immediately obvious to me how to do this. I'm using [SBT](https://github.com/ktoso/sbt-jmh).

Comment: JMH passes any arguments passed to it. You can just add them to the command line,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I read sbt-jmh docs right, it passes the application options to JMH runner with `jmh:run ...`. So, having that JMH command line accepts `--jvmArgs "..."`, I would try to do `jmh:run --jvmArgs "-XX:+PrintGCDetails"`. Or, as @apangin mentions, add `@Fork(jvmArgsAppend = "-XX:+PrintGCDetails")`.

But for your particular use case -- "see how much garbage is generated" -- it might be even better idea to use a bundled GC profiler, activated with `-prof gc`. See the example at [JMHSample_35_Profilers.java#l71](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/7cff26ccc4d3/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_35_Profilers.java#l71).

Answer (score 14):

Use `@Fork` annotation:

```
@Benchmark
@Fork(jvmArgsAppend = "-XX:+PrintGCDetails")
public void someBenchmark() {
    ...
}
```

Note that JVM arguments passed to JMH are also propagated to forked benchmarks.